# Running unit tests in Scala project results in "error: package scala does not exist"

Tags: eclipse, scala

This error occurs whenever an import from scala is attempted. The Scala library is in the classpath, so I don't know what else could cause the problem. I am running Eclipse Kepler with the latest stable Scala library.

Comment: How do you run your test suites?

Comment: How do you import the project? Does your project have the Scala nature?